# Install proxychains from Terminal

Tags: command-line, software-installation

I want to install proxychains from terminal and the code is

```
apt-get install proxychains
```

but it said

```
Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 5):

Execute the same command with sudo

`sudo apt-get install proxychains`

Comment: Can you give a reason for why to use sudo? explain.

Comment: Installation and uninstallation are Administrative tasks. You have to elevate your privileges to allow your user to install. Thats why you need sudo.

Comment: Most of the time you are using Ubuntu you do not have the power to make significant changes to the system such as installing software.  Take a look [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo) for a more detailed explanation

Comment: @Alvar: try ls -l /etc/var/dpkg/lock. You will see something like:-rw-r----- 1 root root 0 mei  5 10:43 /var/lib/dpkg/lock. So only root can do it.

Comment: I know what sudo means I just wanted @thefourtheye to explain is answer more. Since the OP seemed to be new to Ubuntu...

Comment: @Alvar What is OP?

Comment: @thefourtheye the one who asked the question.

Comment: Oh. What is the expansion?

Comment: @thefourtheye OP = Original Poster